# How to give PARAMETERS to batch files .BAT and execute them with System.Shell.execute

Tags: parameters, batch-file, shellexecute

I am developing a software for windows and there is a **function** that I need to **“System.Shell.execute”** a **batch file** but I want it to have **two functions (parameters)**

So when I execute:

`objShell.ShellExecute("file.bat", "PARAMETER1", "", "open", 2);`

it will run the PARAMETER1 in the bat file, and viceverca (for parameter2).

I want to know how i can configure my **batch** file to do that, Ex:

```
@ECHO OFF   

PARAMETER1

::     execute some code here

PARAMETER2  

::     execute some code here
```

(is possible something like that?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a batch label for each function. Simply GOTO the label specified by the 1st batch parameter. Each "function" can access additional parameters starting with `%2`.

```
@echo off
goto %1

:PARAMETER1
REM execute code here
exit /b

:PARAMETER2
REM execute code here
exit /b
```

Comment: Can you please answer the EDIT question.

Comment: @tofran - I don't understand what you are trying to do in your new 2nd question. Also, it is, (well..) a 2nd question. Please remove the EDIT from this question, and then ask a new question, and provide more explanation of what you are attempting to do.

Answer (score 0):

I would make my script a little different:

```
@echo off
goto %1
goto :end

:: functions

:PARAMETER1 comment1
REM execute code here
exit /b 0

:PARAMETER2 comment2
REM execute code here
if %ERRORLEVEL%==1 ECHO goto :error
exit /b 0

:error
ECHO Error occurred with arg %1
timeout 10
exit 1

:: end of script
:end
ECHO Finished
```

Comment: Your `goto :end` is dead code since `goto %1` will result in fatal error if the label does not exist. So this really isn't different than my answer, just obfuscated a bit. There are multiple ways to validate the label before attempting to GOTO - for example, via IF with hard coded label strings, or FINDSTR against `%~f0`. But it doesn't really change the primary concept.

Comment: Can you please answer the EDIT question.

Comment: Your "set" command is wrong.  Besides, you already marked this question as answered.